# How to change PSR log files as only one per day

Tags: php, logging, psr-0

I've used PSR logger to get logs. But it will create just one file for all dates. I need to get separate log files to each date. How to do that?

```
    require_once '../../logger/vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once '../../logger/Psr/Log/Logger.php';
    use Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger;
    use Psr\Log\LogLevel;


    $logPath = '/var/www/html/logs';
    $logger = new Logger($logPath, LogLevel::DEBUG, array ( 'filename' => 'driver_api' , 'extension' => 'log' ));
    $logger->log( $level,  $message , $context);
```

`

Comment: probably you could do something fancy with log rotate, but you for an easy fix why not just add the date at the end of the filename  'filename' => 'driver_api' . data("d-m-Y)

Comment: for log rotate check this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @ElenaRoman Thanks for the idea. But I need to keep today logfile without a date. Like as an Apache error log. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use log rotator

```
protected function log_rotate($logpath, $filename, $extention){
    $logfilename = $logpath.'/'.$filename.'.'.$extention; //not needed when included
    $logfilestokeep = 15;
    $fileDate = '';



    if (file_exists($logfilename)) {
        if (date("Y-m-d", filemtime($logfilename)) !== date('Y-m-d')) {
            $fileDate = date("Y-m-d", filemtime($logfilename));
            $newName = $logpath .'/'.$filename. "_" . $fileDate.'.'.$extention;

            if (file_exists($logfilename)) {
                rename($logfilename, $newName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```